# image error occured if not exist

Tags: jquery

i want to show images in grid. but if image is not exist i want to show 
no-image.png. but currently if image is not exist it will show error on console

```
"GET http://localhost/images/image.png 404 (Not Found)".
```

i dont want this error if image is not exist. please help me what should i do..
here is my code.

```
var image = $('<img src="/images/image.png" />');
            if (image.attr('width') > 0)
                return '/images/No_image.png';
            else
                return '/images/image.png';
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you can use the `error()` event of the `img` element. If that event is raised then you know that the image was not successfully loaded, either from a server error, or a 404. In this case you can then change the `src` attribute to your placeholder. Try this:

```
$('<img src="/images/image.png" />').error(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', '/images/No_image.png');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code to check if image exist

```
function isImageExists(imgSrc, callBackAfterCheck) {
   var img = new Image();
   img.onload = function() { callBackAfterCheck(true) };
   img.onerror = function() {callBackAfterCheck(false) };
   img.src = imgSrc;
}

function callBackAfterCheck(status){
   if(status == true){
    //do your stuff here
    console.log('image Exist');
   }else{
    //do your stuff here
    console.log('image not Exist');
   }
}

 var imageUrl = 'your_image_url';
 isImageExists(imageUrl, callBackAfterCheck);
```

Comment: bro "GET http://localhost/images/image.png 404 (Not Found)". this error is showing in unconsole